# Html.DropDownList not setting selected item on GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this problem were I am setting a selectlist with a selected item.
On GET request the select list is populated but the selected item is not set.
On POST request the select list is populated with the new selected value.

Code is the same for both ActionResult functions as is the view (both using the same view).

This is part of my Student class

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
```

This is the code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Student student = _dB.Students.Where(std => std.AccountID == accountID).FirstOrDefault();

    student.Titles = new SelectList(_dB.Titles, "Id", "Description", student.Title);

    return View(student);
}


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Student student)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Student studentSave = _dB.Students.Where(stud => stud.StudentID == student.StudentID).FirstOrDefault();
                studentSave.Name = student.Name;
                studentSave.Surname = student.Surname;
                studentSave.Email = student.Email;
                studentSave.Title = student.Title;
                studentSave.DOB = student.DOB;
                studentSave.Telnum = student.Telnum;
                studentSave.AddressLine1 = student.AddressLine1;
                studentSave.AddressLine2 = student.AddressLine2;
                studentSave.Town = student.Town;
                studentSave.PostCode = student.PostCode;
                studentSave.Country = student.Country;

                _dB.SaveChanges();
                
            }

            ViewBag.Submitted = true;

            student.Titles = new SelectList(_dB.Titles, "Id", "Description", student.Title);

            return View(student);

    }
```

This is the code in my View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title", Model.Titles, new { @class = "form-control shadow-none" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Values are passed correctly when debugging up to `Html.DropDownList` but on render the selected item is not set (when performing GET request).

I have tried various methods of populating the select list and all have rendered the same result.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `Title` value to the fourth parameter for [`DropDownList(String, String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, Object, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#system-web-webpages-html-htmlhelper-dropdownlist(system-string-system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-web-webpages-html-selectlistitem))-system-object-system-object)).

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title", 
    "",
    Model.Titles, 
    Model.Title,
    new { @class = "form-control shadow-none" })
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Html.DropDownListFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-selectextensions-dropdownlistfor-2(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1))))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-web-mvc-selectlistitem))-system-object)) to bind the `Title` value to the drop-down list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, 
    Model.Titles, 
    new { @class = "form-control shadow-none" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from your initialization of the selectList, you specified the data value as "Id" but then you say that the selected value is an entire object `student.Title` you should try this `new SelectList(_dB.Titles, "Id", "Description", student.Title.Id)`